# Multiple graphs and direction (rankdir) in one dot file (gvpack not doing what I want)

Tags: graphviz, subgraph

**DISCLAIMER** : I am French and so I am sorry in advance for my poor english. Please be nice, thank you very much.

So I have multiple files and graphs with different direction (`rankdir`). I must merge them to have one big coherent graph.

There is a part on the bottom with the classic `toptobottom` direction :

```
strict digraph G {
    compound = true
    ranksep = "1 equally"
    node [shape=box, style=rounded]    

    render [label="Rendu de l'image"]

    subgraph cluster_controle {
        label = "Contrôle qualité"
        {
            conformite[label="Conforme à la réalité : simulation visuelle"]
            mesure[label="Mesures factuelles"]
            fidelite[label="Fidélité de l'image"]
            perf[label="Performance"]
            nettete[label="Netteté de l'image"]

            nettete -> mesure
            fidelite -> mesure
            perf -> mesure
            mesure -> conformite
        }
    }
    render -> perf [lhead=cluster_controle]
}
```

[image: Render of the code above. Main part of the whole graph.]

Now I have two other parts : one that must go on the left of the main graph, and the other on the right.

Left :

```
strict digraph O {
    compound = true
    ranksep = "1 equally"
    rankdir=LR
    node [shape=box, style=rounded]
    subgraph cluster_opti {
        label = "Optimisation du calcul"
        tracking [label="Eye-tracking"]
        {
            rank=same
            fovea [label="Fovea rendering"]
            load [label="Equilibrage de charge"]
            denoiser [label="Denoiser"]
        }
        ia_denoise [label="IA"]

        fovea -> tracking
        load -> tracking
        denoiser -> tracking
        ia_denoise -> denoiser
    }
}
```

[image: Left part of the graph]

Right part :

```
strict digraph A {
    compound = true
    ranksep = "1 equally"
    rankdir=RL
    node [shape=box, style=rounded]
    subgraph cluster_precalcul {
        label = "Anticipation"
        precalcul [label="Précalcul des images"]
        {
            rank=same
            ia_mouv [label="IA (mouvements)"]
            caching [label="Caching"]
        }
        ia_mouv -> precalcul
        caching -> precalcul
    }
}
```

[image: Right part of the whole graph]

I tried `gvpack -u` but it does not do what I want. The direction (`rankdir`) of the lef and right part are not taken in account. I also tried `gvpack -g` or `-n` but there is the following error :

```
Error: node render in graph G has no position
Error loading layout info from graph G
```

And now my questions are :

- Is it possible to merge them like I want to in one file ?

  - If yes, how to please ?
- If it is not possible, do I really have to do it in Inkscape by hand ? *sad face*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

- **-array** to combine as graphs (not clusters or nodes)
- **_i**     to combine the files in the order on the command line (not based on size)
- **3**      to request 3 "columns" of graphs (not a 2x2 grid)

  ```
  gvpack -array_i3  part*dot | neato -n2 -Tpng
  ```

[the **gvpack** man page can help if you need to alter justification or margins]

Giving:
[image]

Comment: I tried your command `gvpack -array_i3 first.dot second.dot third.dot` and it gives me two errors : 
`Error: node tracking in graph O has no position
Error loading layout info from graph O`
The graph O is the left part. I do not understand why it does not work...

Comment: Did you run each of your source files through dot  to generate positioning data?   gvpack man page says:  "The input graphs must be in dot format, and must have all  necessary  layout  information. Acceptable input is produced by applying a Graphviz layout program, such as dot or neato, with no -T flag"

Comment: Great!  The man page for gvpack is challenging.